# what does "that" mean?

Tags: pronouns

> The role of science can sometimes be overstated, with its
> advocates slipping into scientism. Scientism is the view that
> the scientific description of reality is the only truth there is.
> With the advance of science, there has been a tendency to slip
> into scientism, and assume that any factual claim can be
> authenticated if and only if the term ‘scientific’ can correctly
> be ascribed to it. The consequence is that non-scientific
> approaches to reality ― *and that can include all the arts,
> religion, and personal*, emotional and value-laden ways of
> encountering the world ― may become labelled as merely
> subjective, and therefore of little account in terms of
> describing the way the world is. The philosophy of science
> seeks to avoid crude scientism and get a balanced view on
> what the scientific method can and cannot achieve.

1. The consequence is that ~ reality — *and **that** can include all the arts,
   religion, and personal*

What's ***that*** here?

Comment: I would expect to see 'of little use' or 'of little help' there; maybe you have a bad copy or the original text was badly edited.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a mistranscription of [*...therefore of little **account** in terms of describing the way the world is.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22therefore+of+little+account+in+terms+of+describing+the+way+the+world+is%22)

Comment: Thx. The question was edited.

Comment: 'That' refers to 'reality' - "pronoun referring to a specific thing previously mentioned, known, or understood." (dictionaries).

Answer (score 2):

*That* refers to the phrase *non-scientific approaches to reality*.

It is singular because it refers not to the approaches, but to the linguistic object made up of those words.

Comment: I'm not sure it *has* to be singular. In fact, *...and **those** can include...* might be slightly preferable to me anyway, to unambiguously convey that what follows is a list of "non--scientific approaches to reality", rather than a list of "[aspects of] **reality**". But at the end of the day I'm sure I'd just sidestep the issue and write ***which** can include...* - which I feel could be significantly easier to parse in the written form (I see no problem with the *spoken* version, but what with all the dashes and everything, I think as *text* it's potentially challenging for almost anyone).

Comment: I took the question to be asking what an existing text means by _that_, and I explained. Certainly other options are possible.